# AddError Not working on before update Trigger

Tags: before-trigger, adderror

I have a newbie issue.... hahaah

This is my code where I Need to avoid an update and show an error messaje if a lookup field has the status "Cerrado" but whith this code, the objects are being updated.
What is wrong?

```
trigger myTriggerName on CustomObject__c (before update) {
 for(CustomObject__c mycustomObject : Trigger.New){
    if ( mycustomObject.Puesto_r.Estado_c == 'Cerrado'){
                  mycustomObject.AddError( Error Message.');
      }   
}
}
```

Note:
I'm using a Puesto__c object that has Estado__c with "Cerrado" value just to test the messaje.

Comment: are you sure that `mycustomObject.Puesto_r.Estado_c` is not `Closed` (`Cerrado`)?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual contents of mycustomObject.Puesto__r.Estado__c, what does it contain? A lookup field usually contains an Id.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that the relationship object `Puesto__r` is not in context in the trigger

You need to query for these relationship objects, Trigger context is only the sobject of the trigger, not its parents or children

```
trigger myTriggerName on CustomObject__c (before update) {
 Set<Id> puestoIds = new Set<Id>();

 for (CustomObject__c mycustomObject : Trigger.New) {
    puestoIds.add(myCustomObject.Puesto__c);
 }

 Map<Id, Puesto__c> puestosById = new Map<Id, Puesto__c> (
   [SELECT Id, Estado__c FROM Puesto__c WHERE ID IN :puestoIds]);
 
 for (CustomObject__c mycustomObject : Trigger.New) {
    if (myCustomObject.Puesto__c != null &&
            puestosById.get(myCustomObject.Puesto__c).Estado_c == 'Cerrado') {
        mycustomObject.AddError( Error Message.');
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried querying but did not work

Comment: I Used: before CustomObject__c mycustomObject = [select Id,Name,Puesto__r.Estado__c from CustomObject__c where Id in: Trigger.new];

Comment: @MartinLarizzate - see updated answer

Comment: oh good idea. Let me check it. Thanks!